# How to generate random 0 and 1 with 80-20 probability in sql server

Tags: sql-server, random

I have a Table with 10 records, I have a column (name:RandomNumber) ,that its data type is bit .
now I want to insert data in to this column randomly in such a way that 80 percent of record (8 record) get 0 randomly and 20 percent (2 record) get 1.

For Example Like this:

| Id | RandomNumber |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 |
| 7 | 0 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 9 | 0 |
| 10 | 0 |

Comment: Do you want exactly 8/10 to be 0, or do you want a probability of 80% that it's 0?

Comment: The table will _always_ have _exactly_ 10 rows? So every time you query the table you want exactly 2 to have 1 and 8 to have 0, and it could be the same distribution or different distribution every time? Think of rolling dice and getting snake eyes 10 times in a row, that's possible with "random" too...

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker hi , every time we want different distribution based on the input that we get in application

Comment: But again that's not necessarily what you get with random. Do they have to be _different each time_ (e.g. you don't want it to be the same as last time), or is it ok if the output is sometimes the same two times in a row? Randomizing 1 in 5 is not exactly going to lead to very "random"....

Answer (score 2):

One way is use `ORDER BY NEWID()` to assign 1 to two rows (20%) and assign 0 to others (remaining 80%) by excluding those assigned 1.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Example(
    Id int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Test PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO dbo.Example VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);

WITH ones AS (
    SELECT TOP (2) Id, 1 AS RandomNumber
    FROM dbo.Example
    ORDER BY NEWID()
)
SELECT Id, 0 AS RandomNumber
FROM dbo.Example
WHERE Id NOT IN(SELECT Id FROM ones)
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, 1 AS RandomNumber
FROM ones
ORDER BY Id;
```

Alternatively, use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID())` and a `CASE` expression:

```
WITH example AS (
    SELECT Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) AS rownum
    FROM dbo.Example
)
SELECT Id, CASE WHEN rownum <= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS RandomNumber
FROM example
ORDER BY Id;
```